# How to convey the jwt id token received from the Oauth flow to the mobile app?

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, openid-connect

The consumer of the app server (stateless rest api) is a mobile app invoking the app server endpoints via SSL.

I want to pass the jwt id token (received from the oauth/openidconnect flow) to the mobile app so that the mobile app can pass the jwt id token in the header of subsequent endpoint requests.

I have the following options:

1. Server side session - jwt id token is stored on the server (file system or db) and the session id is sent to mobile app via cookie. Subsequent endpoint invocations check token from session.
2. Client side session - signed cookie containing the jwt token is sent to the mobile app.  Subsequent endpoint invocations check the token from cookie.
3. Token based - jwt token is sent as repsome body. Subsequent endpoint invocations pass the token in header.

Each of above technique allows the app server endpoint to know who the caller is (by reading the jwt token).

Which is the secure way amongst the above options for the app server to convey the token to the mobile app?

Answer (score 1):

The standard option is for the mobile app to receive tokens using the AppAuth pattern, according to [this RFC8252 section](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7). As you are discovering, if an API does the OAuth flow, the app cannot easily ask the API for tokens, since there is no credential that can be sent in this request (cookies cannot be issued to mobile views).

To see how this looks, see these resources:

- [Curity iOS AppAuth Example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/swift-ios-appauth/)
- [Curity Android AppAuth Example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/kotlin-android-appauth/)
- [React Native AppAuth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth)